# Getting segmentation fault in vscode but not in online compiler (gdb)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, linked-list, segmentation-fault

Basically, I am trying to write a function that takes two linked lists of the same length as an argument and return the sum of the numbers of each linked list in such a way that each node is multiplied by a power of 10 depending on its number and added to the other nodes, however, when running the code in *vscode*, i seem to get a **segmentation fault** on line 15:
`l1sum += temp1->val * i;` whereas when running the code on *online gdb* compiler, correct results are given with zero shown errors, may i know why this happens?

This is the whole code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct ListNode {
     int val;
     struct ListNode *next;
};

void addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2){
    int l1sum = 0, l2sum = 0, i=1;
    struct ListNode * temp1 = l1;
    struct ListNode * temp2 = l2;
    while(temp1 != NULL && temp2 != NULL)
    {
        l1sum += temp1->val * i;
        l2sum += temp2->val * i;
        i = i*10;
        temp1 = temp1->next;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }
    free(temp1);
    free(temp2);  
    printf("l1sum: %d\n", l1sum);
    printf("l2sum: %d\n", l2sum);
}

int main()
{
    struct ListNode * head1 = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    struct ListNode * head2 = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    struct ListNode * second1 = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    struct ListNode * second2 = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    struct ListNode * third1 = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    struct ListNode * third2 = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));

    head1->val = 2;
    second1->val = 4;
    third1->val = 3;
    head1->next = second1;
    second1->next = third1;

    head2->val = 5;
    second2->val = 6;
    third2->val = 4;
    head2->next = second2;
    second2->next = third2;

    addTwoNumbers(head1, head2);
}
```

Comment: You aren't setting the `next` pointer to `NULL` in the third node of each list, so the `next` pointer value is indeterminate. It may or may not be `NULL`.

Comment: Why are you `free`ing `temp1` and `temp2`? You haven't allocated them yourself in the function scope. Freeing them will free the arguments, `l1` and `l2` and you won't be allowed to access them after calling this function. This is not your immediate problem, but it looks like a good way of introducing bugs.

Comment: If something works with one compiler but not with another, it is almost certainly a sign of Undefined Behavior, like for example uninitialized variables.

Comment: I just had a similar issue. I eventually realized that I accessed some code `obj->method()` in the vscode debugger watch panel, which triggered the segmentation fault. whoops

Answer (score 0):

What everyone is basically commenting on is that when linked lists are built and there is a "next" pointer, the value placed into that variable in the final list entry is "NULL".  If that is omitted, it is basically a guess if that variable will contain a NULL value or have some garbage value that will point to an area of memory that it should not point to.  Some times one may get lucky and the values will be NULL when the program runs, but that is a gamble.  With that, here is a subset of your code with the additional code that terminates the linked lists with the NULL pointer.

```
    head1->val    = 2;
    second1->val  = 4;
    third1->val   = 3;
    head1->next   = second1;
    second1->next = third1;
    third1->next  = NULL;       /* Added to ensure the end of the list is known */

    head2->val    = 5;
    second2->val  = 6;
    third2->val   = 4;
    head2->next   = second2;
    second2->next = third2;
    third2->next  = NULL;       /* Added to ensure the end of the list is known */
```

Give that a try both outside of vscode and within vscode.